# Specman how to read a specific line from a file, with no loop

Tags: specman

I have a long file, and I want to read a specific line not from the first sequence lines.
 is there a way to do it without looping all over the file and counting the lines?

For example files.read,  which get an index from which line to read?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the predefined method `files.get_text_lines()`.